# How to make anonymous function work in Red/Rebol

Tags: red, rebol3

In Red/Rebol, parentheses `()` can be used to evaluate expressions like this:

```
>> (1 + 2 3 + 4)
== 7
```

However, when I use parentheses to evalute an anonymous function, it fails(please see the following code). Why? And how to make an anonymous function work?

```
>> (func [x y][x + y] 2 3)
== 3  ;;I think it should be 5.
```

PS:

```
>> do func [x y] [x + y]
== func [x y][x + y]
>> type? do func [x y] [x + y]
== function!
>> (do func [x y] [x + y]) 2 3
== 3  ;; why does this anonymous function still not work?
>> ((do func [x y] [x + y]) 2 3)
== 3  ;; This does not work too.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why?

The reason is quite simple: there's no anonymous function in your code. It will become more evident if you scan its content as data:

```
>> code: quote (func [x y][x + y] 2 3)
== (func [x y] [x + y] 2 3)
>> forall code [probe type? code/1]
word!
block!
block!
integer!
integer!
== integer!
```

That is to say: `func [x y][x + y]` is a `word!` followed by 2 `block!`s, not a function. Once evaluated though, it will yield back a function whose literal form will look exactly the same. `func` is itself a function (aka function constructor) that *creates* another function.

```
>> type? probe func [x y][x + y]
func [x y][x + y]
== function!
```

In your example `3` is returned exactly for that reason: the interpreter evaluates each expression in sequence; the first expression is a function call `func [x y][x + y]` that takes two blocks and returns a function; the remaining expressions are literals `2` and `3` that evaluate to themselves; the result of the last expression is always returned in Red, so you get `3`. Parentheses in such case are superfluous.

```
>> 0 + 1 2 3
== 3
>> func [x y][x + y] 2 3
== 3
```

So, if you want to evaluate a function anonymously, you first need to create a `function!` value from spec and body blocks with the help of function constructor (e.g. `func`, `function`, `has`, `does` or some other one that you wrote yourself), and only then apply it to the arguments. The most common way to do so is `do reduce` pattern:

```
>> do reduce [func [x y][x + y] 2 3]
== 5
```

`reduce` evaluates each sub-expression within a block (`func` creates a `function!`, `2` and `3` evaluate to themselves), and `do` then interprets it (applies an anonymous function to two arguments).

Here are some other approaches, so that you can get a grip of the concept:

```
>> do compose [(func [x y][x + y]) 2 3]
== 5
>> do head insert [2 3] function [x y][x + y]
== 5
>> do reverse append [3 2] make function! [[x y][x + y]]
== 5
>> λ: func [spec body code][do compose [(func spec body) (code)]]
== func [spec body code][do compose [(func spec body) (code)]]
>> λ [x y][x + y][2 3]
== 5
```

---

As to why `do func [x y][x + y]` works that way: this by design, to prevent variadic function calls. You can read a bit more on the rationale of it [here](https://github.com/red/red/issues/3553).

All functions in Rebol/Red have a fixed arity and evaluate only as many expressions as they need; function returning to the call-site and consuming the remaining arguments (like e.g. in Lisp) would go against this rule.

```
   ((lambda (x y)(+ x y)) 1 2)
=> 3
```

As a historical curiosity, Rebol3 had a `return/redo` refinement which allowed functions to do just that, and which was later [removed](https://www.curecode.org/rebol3/ticket.rsp?id=2121) for the reasons I outlined above.

Evaluation in the Rebol family is "layered", so to speak: values returned as results from functions don't get immediately re-evaluated if they are applicative, but rather need an extra pass from a top-level call to the evaluator (e.g. `do` or `reduce`).

Comment: `func` `[x y]` `[x + y]` in a block are just three elements of the block. They must be `reduce`d before being a function. Many thanks for these detail description!

Comment: And I updated my query. Would you have a look at it? Thank you

Comment: @lyl Sure. I've extended my answer to address your post-scriptum.